# remove slide up effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, drop-down-menu

I am using the following javascript code for the drop-down menu. It has come default with the template. Now I want to remove the slide up option as it flickers a lot. I want that menu just fades out or simply hidden after the mouse-out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j('.menu-nav li').hover(
        function() {
              $j(this).addClass("active");
              $j(this).find('.ulwrapper').stop(false, true).slideDown();
          $j(this).find('.ulwrapper .ulwrapper').stop(false, true).slideUp();
        },
        function() {
              $j(this).removeClass("active");        
              $j(this).find('div').stop(false, true).slideUp();
        }
          );
        $j('.ulwrapper').hover(function() {
              $j('.parent').addClass("active_tab");
            }, function() {
              $j('.parent').removeClass("active_tab");        
        });
});

</script>
```

Will really appreciate the solutions.

Comment: Hi, try to replace ".slideUp()" by ".hide()" or ".fadeOut(500)". BTW, there are a lot of effects that you can find here http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Comment: If you just want to change the effect because this one flickers, change your css for the dropdown so it has padding instead of margin, then the slideUp/Down won't flicker.

Answer (score 1):

```
function() {

     $j(this).addClass("active");

        $j(this).find('.ulwrapper').stop(false, true).slideDown();

        $j(this).find('.ulwrapper .ulwrapper').stop(false, true).fade();

    },

    function() {

        $j(this).removeClass("active");        

        $j(this).find('div').stop(false, true).fade();

    }
```

Hope this helps :-)